# For loop isn't finding all files in a directory

Tags: bash, loops

I've got a few folders that I had a script running to rename some files. Up until around 300 files per folder it wasn't having any issues, however, now it's like the for loop just doesn't see all the files.

I have a file called Folder_List.txt that has the links to all the folders I want it to parse through, and another that archives already renamed files so it doesn't double up.

Each video file has 2 associated files so it renamed the 3 total files all the same, and then proceeds to the next, but now, once it gets to the file titled S01E099 it stops renaming and I can't figure out why.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Setup the folder parser
folder="/mnt/user/Storage/Google Drive/Server Files/Downloader/Folder_List.txt"
while IFS=$'\r' read path; do

#Check to ensure the location exists
if [[ -d "$path" ]]
then
cd "$path"

#Declare Variable
c=0
filename_old=0
archive="/mnt/user/Storage/Google Drive/Server Files/Downloader/Episodes_archive.txt"

#Loop
for i in *; do 

    #Gets the extension
    ext=$(echo $i | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')

    #Gets Season
    season=$(echo "$i" | awk -F 'E' '{print $1}')

    #Gets title
    title=$(echo $i | awk -F ' - ' '{print $2}')
    title=$(echo $title | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')

    #Checks for episode matches
    if [ ! "$title" == "$filename_old" ]
    then
        filename_old=$title
        ((c++))
    fi

    #Gets the Episode number (needs to be after the episode match check)
    epnum=$(printf %02d $c)

    #Creates final filename
    filename_final=$season"E"$epnum" - "$title.$ext

    #Creates the naming structure for archiving
    filename_archive=$path$season"E"$epnum.$ext

    #Check if file was already renamed
    if grep -Fq "$filename_archive" < "$archive"
    then 
        #If file was already renamed do:
        continue
    else
        #Add renamed file to archive
        echo "$filename_archive"$'\r' >> "$archive"
        echo "$filename_final renamed"
        #Rename File
        mv "$i" "$filename_final"
    fi

done
fi

done < "$folder"
```

If it helps clarify anything, the files that are to be renamed are formatted as: S01E789 - episode title.mkv

It should just rename all the files in the folder, but it's stopping halfway for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running the script under `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! it looks like I must have already had upto 115 in the archive so it was skipping the files. I've removed those filename from the archive and its working again. It's missing a few files but now that I know about set -xv I can likely troubleshoot my way out. Much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, `ext=$(echo $i | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')` is orders-of-magnitude slower than `ext=${i##*.}` and [buggy besides](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and/or [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for best-practice string-manipulation approaches

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy I'm all self taught so I'm sure there are many ways I'm not doing things properly. I'll take a read through the documents you've linked and I've tweaked it in my code. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I must have deleted a few files previously or something because the archive had upto file 115 already in it, so it was skipping any more files it found because it thought they were already renamed.

A big thanks to @choroba for the assistance.